# Unable to parse double values in csv

Tags: apache-nifi

Source csv:

```
ReportDay;SKU;ProductName;Price;Type;ShowsCondition;Impressions;Clicks;CTR;CPM;Budget;Orders;Revenue;ModelOrders;RevenueByModel
15.04.2021;1362254;Product1;71,00;Search;Shelf;1;0;0,00;35,00;0,04;0;0,00;0;0,00
15.04.2021;145406;Product2;129,00;Promo;Shelf;1;0;0,00;35,00;0,04;0;0,00;0;0,00
```

My custom schema to parse csv:

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "SKU",
    "namespace": "test",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "ReportDay", "type": "string"},
        {"name": "SKU", "type": ["long","null"]},
        {"name": "ProductName", "type": ["string","null"]},
        {"name": "Price", "type": ["double","null"]},
        {"name": "Type", "type": ["string","null"]},
        {"name": "ShowsCondition", "type": ["string","null"]},
        {"name": "Impressions", "type": ["long","null"]},
        {"name": "Clicks", "type": ["long","null"]},
        {"name": "CTR", "type": ["double","null"]},
        {"name": "CPM", "type": ["double","null"]},
        {"name": "Budget", "type": ["double","null"]},
        {"name": "Orders", "type": ["long","null"]},
        {"name": "Revenue", "type": ["double","null"]},
        {"name": "ModelOrders", "type": ["long","null"]},
        {"name": "RevenueByModel", "type": ["double","null"]}
    ]
}
```

Also settings:
[image]

While I'm trying to read .csv with this reader in `UpdateRecord` processor I get an error:

```
Error while getting next record. Root cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,00"
```

If I'll change all `double` types to `string` it will parse it with no problem. But I store these values as `numeric` in my DB, so I need to "read" these values as double type, not string. What did I wrong?

Comment: I assume this is because your doubles use a comma as the separator rather than a dot. I don't think there is a param to set the number locale. Best path would be to change your source data to use dots. Otherwise, you could UpdateRecord to replace commas with dots https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#replace and that would let them parse as doubles.

Comment: I cant change source csv, it comes from REST API. I'll try to replace commas.

Comment: you may replace all ',' with '.' after initial fetch before updaterecord. you should consider unnecessary replacements.

Comment: Does it work if you set the CSV Parser property to Jackson?

Comment: @mattyb, doesn't work.

Comment: @yaprak What do u mean about unnecessary replacements? How can I change `,` to `.` before `UpdateRecord`? With `ReplaceText`?

Comment: yes you can use ReplaceText. I meant be careful. don't corrupt your data. basic literal replace may or may not be enough